# Resources not found after building a project in Netbeans 12

Tags: java, jar

I have a java application that runs correctly when I execute it from Netbeans.
If I execute it as a .jar it does not work. I am getting the error **"Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/ParseException"**
The error is ocurring in this command:

```
Object object = parser.parse(new FileReader("src\\main\\resources\\companies.json"));
```

I think the problem is that I am not defining the resource paths properly. See screenshot

[image]

---------------UPDATE-------------------------

After spending many hours trying to solve this s*** problem, I still can not run the application from a jar. I also try to call the ressources like that:

```
InputStream inputStream = NewMain.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/companies.json");
```

but the same problem as before. When I start the applicaion from a batch file I get this message:

[image]

I am totally blocked. I would really apreciate if someone could help me

Comment: I downloaded json-simple-1.1.1.jar and stored it in the same folder where the .jar of my application is and I am still having the same problem. As I said, I think the problem might be in the way that I am defining the resource paths. I also tried that: Object object = parser.parse(new FileReader(NewMain.class.getResource("companies.json").getPath()));

The result is the same. I can run the application from Netbeans but the .jar is not working

Answer (score 0):

How are you generating the jar? This seems like the json class cannot be found at runtime and you need to add it to the classpath when building.

You can also check the responses at [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/ParseException with eclipse and spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657585/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-json-simple-parser-parseexception-with-eclip).

Comment: I am building the project from Netbeans