# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when compiling maven project

Tags: java, maven, build-dependencies

I'm trying to make a simple currency converter program in java with maven and am using json data so I try to import the "org.json.simple" dependency and have the dependency tag in my pom.xml. However, when I compile I get "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/JSONParser."
my pom.xml file:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.1</version>
          <configuration>
              <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
              </descriptorRefs>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <mainClass>com.myapp.app.App</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>make-assembly</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

the code that I am trying to run:

```
import org.json.simple.*;
import org.json.simple.parser.*;

public class Api {
public static String getFinalAmount() {
    String finalAmount = "";
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("/Users/User/Desktop/course.json"));
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)obj;
        finalAmount = (String)jsonObject.get("new_amount");
        return finalAmount;

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return finalAmount;
  }
}
```

I have already tried adding the maven assembly plugin and the dependency plugin with neither helping. I'm not sure what to try next since I don't usually use Java or maven and I haven't been able to find much on this topic. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post you entire pom file?

Comment: Yes sorry the post was flagged as spam if I put the entire pom file but I put it in a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/WUjBiBfw. Thank you.

Comment: While it is possible that you post got flagged for something, I doubt that it was spam. If you are sure of that let me have a look by giving me a link to the deleted post. It should be possible to directly provide enough information without getting flagged (for whatever). You are indeed risking getting your question closed if you do not provide all information directly...

Comment: The project is not a spring boot project so that should not be the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Code and json-simple Dependecy are looking fine.
Check if you were able to see json-simple-1.1.1.jar file in your classpath if not try adding it. you should be able to get JSONParser form org.json.simple.*

Comment: I generated the classpath into a [textfile](https://pastebin.com/GDVTRyWF) and it shows json-simple jar as the first one. I'm not too sure where to go from here. Thank you.

Comment: I believe it might be issue with IDE which may not be able to pick the Jar.
This similar issue is already resolved here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31278832/4046325